# ddply + summarise function column name input

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use `ddply` and `summarise` together from the `plyr` package but am having difficulty parsing through column names that keep changing...In my example i would like something that would parse in X1 programatically rather than hard coding in X1 into the ddply function.

setting up an example

```
require(xts)
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)
require(lubridate)
t <- xts(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10), Sys.Date()-1000:1)
t.df <- data.frame(coredata(t))
t.df <- cbind(day=wday(index(t), label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE), t.df)
t.df.l <- melt(t.df, id.vars=c("day",colnames(t.df)[2]), measure.vars=colnames(t.df)[3:ncol(t.df)])
```

This is the bit im am struggling with....

```
cor.vars <- ddply(t.df.l, c("day","variable"), summarise, cor(X1, value))
```

i do not want to use the term X1 and would like to use something like

```
cor.vars <- ddply(t.df.l, c("day","variable"), summarise, cor(colnames(t.df)[2], value))
```

but that comes up with the error: `Error in cor(colnames(t.df)[2], value) : 'x' must be numeric`

I also tried various other combos that parse in the vector values for the x argument in cor...but for some reason none of them seem to work...

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible? I still get errors after loading the `plyr`, `reshape2` and `xts` packages.

Comment: added in the libridate package...as a required library...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is probably not the intended usage for `summarize` and there must be much better approaches to your problem, the direct answer to your question is to use `get`:

```
ddply(t.df.l, c("day","variable"), summarise, cor(get(colnames(t.df)[2]), value))
```

Edit: here is for example one approach that is in my opinion better suited to your problem:

```
ddply(t.df.l, c("day", "variable"), function(x)cor(x["X1"], x["value"]))
```

Above, `"X1"` can be also replaced by `2` or the name of a variable holding `"X1"`, etc. It depends how you want to programmatically access the column.

Comment: Brilliant thanks....if this isn't what `summarise` was for...then are there better ways of doing the above?