# Getting column by column name in plyr using summarize inside a function

Tags: r, plyr

I know how to use column names sorted in strings using ddply and summarize outside functions, via get, as detailed in [ddply + summarise function column name input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724745/ddply-summarise-function-column-name-input). This works when working interactively from the prompt.

However, this doesn't works when I try to do it inside a function.
I also know that there are other ways to solve this problem, as detailed in [How can I use variable names to refer to data frame columns with ddply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869005/how-can-i-use-variable-names-to-refer-to-data-frame-columns-with-ddply). I just could avoid summarise. But the thing is that I want to understand how it works (I'm currently rereading Hadley's excellent book, which has just moved to http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)

As this is similar to what happens with data.table, I provide a comparison

```
require(data.table)
require(plyr)

dt = data.table(Alpha = 1:3, Beta = head(LETTERS,n=3))


testDt <- function(dt,colName) {
  dt[,mean(get(colName))]
}

testPlyr <- function(dt,colName) {
  ddply(.data=dt,.variables=NULL,.fun=summarise,mean(get(colName)))
}
```

testDt works perfectly

```
testDt(dt,"Alpha")
```

but testPlyr fails when you do

```
testPlyr(dt,"Alpha")
```

Surely data.table and plyr deal with expressions inside their calls differently.

I tried also with

```
testPlyr <- function(dt,colName) {
  e = environment()
  ddply(.data=dt,.variables=NULL,.fun=summarise,mean(get(colName,envir=e)))
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas??

Comment: I asked a similar question before. Maybe you may find some useful comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798218/r-passing-value-to-an-internal-functions-not-find

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/10178203/817778

Comment: @eddi Yes, I know about eval(parse()) but I'm was looking for a non "dynamic SQL" kind of approach

Comment: @linp looking at the old hadley discussion might help, thanks

Comment: @Juancentro why do you use `ddply` if you know `data.table`?

Comment: @eddi most of the time I use data.table for its superior performance, but sometimes, when performance is not an issue, I try ddply, as to not to forget its syntax for when dplyr is finally in production :) . Also, I find that sometimes ddply code is clearer than the equivalent data.table code

Comment: I'm curious about cases of the latter

Comment: @eddi Don't want to start a holy war here! It's a matter of taste. Although more verbose, a call to ddply is almost readable out loud, which, to someone who doesn't know R, it's a plus. data.table calls are more cryptic if the guy doesn't know R. As I said before, trivial detail. If in doubt, I'll stick with data.table

Comment: Don't use summarise: use regular subsetting operations: `function(df) data.frame(m = mean(df[[colName]]))`

Comment: @hadley Yes, as I said in the question, I know there are workarounds, I was only curious if there is a way to make it work with summarize, as to "enbiggen" my knowledge of expressions and non standard evaluation

Comment: @Juancentro not that'd I'd recommend - you can do it, but the point of summarise is to do non-standard evaluation to save typing; so using non-standard evaluation on top of a function that already does non-standard evaluation is not the greatest idea. (That said, see also `plyr::here`)